# Pegando dados de uma url

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho a url de um site, http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm, onde eu coloco um endereço e clicando no botão 'Search' o site me dá as coordenadas desse endereço, latitude e longitude, blz!
Copiei o código desse site e quero que a busca, pelas coordenadas desse endereço, seja feita sem precisar clicar no botão 'Search'.
Já tentei colocar a chamada da função em onload da form e não adiantou.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Valeu.

Comment: O site em questão utiliza a API do Google Maps. Não seria mais fácil você utilizar diretamente a API do Google também?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, já tentei e não consegui, dizia que a chave, se eu não me engano, não era válida.

Comment: Você criou uma chave para a API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, exatamente!
Segui um tutorial que peguei do site http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/default.asp. Posso tentar novamente e se der problemas, novamente, mandar o aviso de erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aconselho você a utilizar a API do Google diretamente. O seguinte trecho de código (usando jQuery para requisição Ajax) obtém a latitude e a longitude de um endereço passado por parâmetro:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var endereco = encodeURIComponent("Praça dos Três Poderes - Brasília");
  $.get("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + endereco,
    function(data) {
      if (data.status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $("#result").html("Endereço não encontrado!");
        return;
      }

      var latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      var longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      $("#result").html("Latitude: " + latitude + "<br/>Longitude: " + longitude);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Porém o recomendável é você utilizar a API do Google para o Javascript (você deverá configurar uma chave de API no painel de controle das API's do Google). Siga o passo a passo em https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HTML5

Comment: publiquei o mapa com a API Key que gerei e continua dando o mesmo problema. Veja o aviso http://fluxojoin.com.br/google-maps-w3school.html

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está o link para obter a chave que ele comentou para utilizar a API do Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Porém é importante lembrar que, assim como está escrito na documentação:

> Se a utilização da API do Google Maps de seu aplicativo ultrapassar os limites de uso, você deverá carregar a API do Google Maps usando uma chave de API para adquirir cota adicional.

Comment: Foi esse link mesmo que gerei a API key, @waveiro.
Sendo que tem esse porém, de ter que adquirir cota adicional.

Comment: Pessoal, to colocando essa div e ela não aparece na tela:
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px; height:380px;"></div>
Tem algum problema se a página for em php?